# Should I use "self" in a block to access class methods?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, class-method

I have a class to perform little conversions like NSDate to NSString with a specific format, etc.

Every methods are class methods, eg `+[Tools humanReadableStringForDate:(NSDate*)date];`

I sometime need my method `+[Tools A]` to call a method `+[Tools B]` of my class, but inside a block.

Should I create a `__block safeSelf = self;` or is it unnecessary because I use class level methods ?

EDIT :
here is an example, not my actual code :

```
@implementation FileManager 

+(void) uploadEveryFile:(void (^)(NSObject*))thingToDo :(NSArray*) fileArray {

    for(NSString *s in fileArray) {
        [[SomeWebAPI uploadFile:s withSuccess:^(NSNumber *responseCode) {
            [self logUploadOk:s];
        }];
    }
}

+(void) logUploadOk:(NSString*)s {
    NSLog(@"File upload ok : %@", s)
}

@end
```

I think this make things clearer. I like to use `self` keyword even for class methods when I can - in this example I can because I am in the same class and refer to a class level method - because it seems to make more sense, and can be helpful if I have to modify my class name.

So is it correct to write it like this ? Is it working but not really correct ? Do I really need to call `logUploadOk` using `[FileManager logUploadOk:s]` ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unnecessary to use `__block` or `__weak` or anything like that. You are talking about `self` in a class method, which is the class object itself. The class object lives for the whole program, so memory management like retain and release on it have no effect. So you don't need to worry about retain cycles.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (NSString *)A
{
    NSString *something = [Tools B];
    NSString *something = [self B]; // both are same inside class method
}
+ (NSString *)B
{
//..
}
```

Comment: +[className Class]: unrecognized selector sent to class for [[self class] B].

Comment: My mistake, `[self]` does work sorry.  Now why did you edit my answer?

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. I would like to use `[self B]`. Since I will be calling it from `[Tools A]`, this will behave the same way as `[Tools B]` but if I modify my `Tools`class name I want things to go smoothly, that's why using `self` is important to me.

Comment: `[Tools B]` and `[self B]` are not the same. If you make a subclass of `Tools` e.g. `SubTools`. Then, in `[SubTools A]`, `[self B]` will call `[SubTools B]`, whereas `[Tools B]` will still call `[Tools B]`

Answer (score -1):

That's unnecessary because you're using class method, not instance method. To call Class methods, you use the class name: `[Tools doThisForMe]`.

However, it sounds like you could use [Objective-C Categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html) in this case. It would allow you to extend the different classes and make your code more readable such as `[myNSDate humanReadableString]`.

In your case, it would go along the lines of:

NSDate+Human.h

```
@interface NSDate (Human)
- (NSString *)humanReadableString;
@end
```

NSDate+Human.m

```
@implementation NSDate (Human)
- (NSString *)humanReadableString {
  // do whatever you want.
  // now 'self' refers to the NSDate instance
}
```

@end

Comment: Yes, indeed this could be interesting ! I always forget about categories... Concerning my question : I do know how to call class methods, but I prefer to use [self method] when I'm calling it from another class method of the same class. Will it work in a block ?

Comment: I don't think that will work, because self refers to the instance. You can always use `+[[self class] someClassMethod];` but I recommend following the general guideline.

Comment: It works, I wanted to know if it was ok/safe to use it. So thanks, it seems not t be

Comment: `self` is better than the name of the class because when you have a subclass, it can call the subclass's implementation of the other method. e.g. when you call `[SubTools A]` it can call `[SubTools B]`

Comment: @StevenLuu: `self` in a class method is the class object.